# taskhostw.exe playing "windows background.wav"

Tags: windows-10

Whenever the system is started or resumes from sleep, the windows notification "dong" sound is played (*most* of the time). Using Process Monitor, I've determined that it is taskhostw.exe triggering the sound.

This is a new computer that I've just installed my normal applications on. Nothing out of the ordinary, it all worked fine on my old machine. My startup applications are shown below.

[image: startup programs]

Comment: What scheduled tasks are configured to run when the system starts/resumes?

Comment: Brilliant! That lead me to realize something else: None of the startup tasks are causing it. It actually happens whenever you connect to a wifi network...

Comment: INTERESTING. When connecting to a wifi network, it only occors if the "Killer Internet Control Center" is open. Makes sense: the app is making a noise cause it's just been connected. But that doesn't explain why it would happen on boot