# „Windows Background.wav“ played by taskhostw.exe when certain programs are opened

Tags: windows-10, audio, notifications

OS: Windows 10 Home 1909 x64, OS build 18363.752

Whenever I open the Control Panel, `Windows Background.wav` plays once the window has appeared. 
It also occurs<sup>1</sup> for *E1 mod*:

- upon opening Firefox
- in Microsoft Edge, upon navigating, creating a new window or closing the last remaining window, sometimes upon opening
- the first time I start typing after starting (not opening from background) Discord
- in the Task Scheduler, upon navigating to History -> Details for the first time after opening the program
- upon opening `services.msc`
- sometimes upon switching to *E1 mod*
- immediately upon opening Inkscape, again several seconds after

There are no visuals associated with the sound playing such as the task bar icon flashing, and no notifications in the notification center.

I have tried some other programs such as PicPick (a snipping tool), paint.net, the built-in calculator and some others, but I have not experienced it with them.

I have run `SFC /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`. Both reported no issues and changed nothing. A virus scan using Malwarebytes was also negative.

I also tried Safe Mode (with networking turned off). There, the problem did not occur in Firefox or the Control Panel. At the time I tested Safe Mode, I hadn't figured out the connection to the keyboard layout yet. I also did not test any other programs.
It did, however, occur multiple times upon booting normally again, in addition to the aforementioned triggers.

Another thing I tried is disabling Settings -> System -> Notifications & actions -> Get notifications from apps and other senders, which also changed nothing.

Using procmon, I found `taskhostw.exe` is running the following sequence of operations multiple times whenever the problem occurs, all with a path value of `C:\Windows\Media\Windows Background.wav`:

```
CreateFile
QueryStandardInformationFile
QueryBasicInformationFile
CloseFile
```

`taskhostw` does not run in Safe Mode.
This sequence is repeated 8 times for the Control Panel and 16 times for Discord, but the sound plays only once. For Inkscape, a test I did with *GER ASCII* shows the sequence repeating 656 times, with the sound playing twice. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgliqp0hthozz1t/Control%20Panel.PML?dl=0) is an example procmon log, recorded when opening the Control Panel with *E1 mod* active, showing only events with paths containing `.wav`.
I have verified that this is actually `C:\Windows\System32\taskhostw.exe`. It uses so little CPU that procexp doesn't even draw a graph for it;
its „private bytes“ are consistently around 9.7 MB, sometimes increasing to around 10 MB. It appears to only ever perform major I/O when the sound is played, for less than 1/10 sec., spiking at a write of ca. 1 MB at most<sup>2</sup>. Its process tree is as follows:

```
wininit.exe
└── services.exe
    └── C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p -s Schedule
        └── taskhostw.exe {222A245B-E637-4AE9-A93F-A59CA119A75E}
```

I was able to find [a Microsoft Community post (in German)](https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/forum/all/alle-10-minuten-benachrichtigungston-taskhostw/4ab61f49-238a-48c2-aab5-42ed32eb3df6) where `taskhostw` with the same arguments caused a similar issue, the main difference being that the OP reports the sound playing exactly every 10 minutes, instead of as a result of certain actions. Unfortunately, that thread died almost immediately and has no useful solutions. The OP included a procmon entry that looks similar to the ones I have encountered.
After disabling Task Scheduler -> `Microsoft\Windows\WDI\ResolutionHost` and rebooting, `taskhostw` still runs. Also, the last time the Resolution Host task ran was on April 9, which leads me to believe the Resolution Host is not responsible.
I also tried disabling almost every Autoruns entry (with *Hide Emtpy Locations*, *Hide Microsoft Entries* and *Hide Windows Entries* enabled), save for the KnownDlls entries, which can't be disabled.
With all these disabled, `taskhostw` still ran and the sounds still played.

I have done an in-place upgrade to try and fix the issue, but it remained.

I do not use „Killer Control Center“, which appears to commonly cause similar issues, as suggested by some [support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/taskhostwexe-causing-windows-exclamationwav-to/968b7eb5-0823-4f55-a224-4fcb791e2884?page=1) [threads](https://superuser.com/q/1279708/613059). I have not found any other useful threads when googling for my issue.

I noticed the issue only occurs when a certain keyboard layout is selected: a version of the [DIN standardised E1 layout (article in German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/E1_(Tastaturbelegung)) downloaded [from here](https://www.europatastatur.de/e1), which I slightly modified and then re-built using [MSKLC 1.4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339). Let's refer to it as „E1 mod“ for the purpose of brevity.
I have used another keyboard layout from the same site before, which appears to be the only place to get the layout I want and is linked to from multiple places on the German Wikipedia, which leads me to believe it is trustworthy. The issue does not occur when using the unedited version („E1“).

I did some testing with MSKLC:

- I recompiled the default German keyboard layout using MSKLC, having modified only the *Name*, *Description*, *Company* and *Copyright* fields („GER mod“). [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6r1i6d5k54hqsx/GerCust.klc?dl=0) is its source file. I installed it using the `setup.exe` generated and rebooted. With this layout selected, the issue still occurs, but seemingly less frequently and consistently<sup>3</sup>.
- Similarly, I created a [new layout](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rn7t6l4yoaj54jh/GerASCII.klc?dl=0) from scratch, which can only type lowercase English letters and other ASCII characters, but no Unicode characters („GER ASCII“). Every key has been assigned exactly one character and has no defined character when any modifier key is pressed. Here, I could only reproduce the issue with Inkscape<sup>3</sup>.

  ---

I'll be happy to provide any further infomation helpful for solving my problem.

Thanks very much in advance!

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>consistently every time, except where otherwise specified</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>There are also very rarely I/O spikes of <100 KB, as well as spikes so small I can only find them by hovering over the very bottom border of the graph, invisibly small like the CPU usage graph, both seemingly at random.</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>It still occurs consistently with Inkscape.</sub>

Comment: I hope you verified the the task in question is really `C:\Windows\System32\taskhostw.exe`. A good tool here is [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer),  which needs to be run as Administrator to fully work on this task. Does it use much CPU?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your comment! I added some info about taskhostw as well as a condition for reproduction I've since observed. With the keyboard layout in the game, it seems unlikely to me that internet access has something to do with it, so I retracted that.
I can use the unedited layout for the time being, but I'm afraid this issue might occur with every keyboard layout I build using MSKLC, so in my opinion this doesn't really resolve anything yet. It's getting late now, but I'll do a bit of testing with MSKLC tomorrow.

Comment: `taskhostw` seems to be started by the Resolution Host. Try to run the Task Scheduler, navigate to *Microsoft\Windows\WDI\ResolutionHost*, disable it and reboot.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, edited accordingly. I also added more „triggers“ as well as the results of some *MSKLC* tests and something I found out about `taskhostw`.

On a more „meta“ note, this question is starting to get less and less readable. I did a little restructuring, but that didn't help much. Do you have any advice how I might structure this better?

Comment: If booting in Safe Mode fixes the problem, use [Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns). To avoid listing Microsoft products use the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*, *Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*. Turn off Startup entries in bunches, to drill down to the startup program that causes this problem. Reboot to test. Re-enable those that proved to be harmless.

Comment: While Safe Mode did fix it, disabling (almost) every Autoruns entry did not. Edited accordingly. Also, I didn't explicitly mention it, but `taskhostw` did not run in Safe Mode. Will edit accordingly.

Comment: You could try disabling the rest of the startups.

Comment: As I said in [my edit](https://superuser.com/revisions/1541037/4): 1.: I can't disable the Malwarebytes services, it won't let me. 2.: The only other things left (Intel Management Engine, KnownDlls) looked vital to the system at first glance, so I looked them up, which – to me –  seemed to confirm that suspicion. If you can confirm they can be disabled without damaging my system, I'll try it.

Comment: Are you disabling using Autoruns? I never heard of KnownDlls. I also have Intel Management Engine installed and in Autoruns it's called MEIx64 and it [seems harmless to disable](https://superuser.com/a/1149757/8672). The last link talks about a device by that name that I found in Device Management under "System devices". You could play it safe by creating a System Restore point first and ensure you have a recovery or installation usb just in case. Disable one at a time and reboot.

Comment: I did use Autoruns. [This](https://i.imgur.com/kpZ80wx.png) is what the KnownDlls entries look like. Apart from them seeming important, I tried unchecking them after creating a restore point, but access was denied. Now, the only things left are KnownDlls and some Malwarebytes services. I can't disable any of those. [This](https://i.imgur.com/1yiIbXQ.png) is the error message that shows when I try.

Comment: I thought you meant a product called KnownDlls - these DLLs cannot be disabled. Malwarebytes is a good product, but for completeness you may disable it via the product itself or uninstall it temporarily, rather than going through Autoruns.

Comment: Uninstalled Malwarebytes, disabled everything else in Autoruns and rebooted ­– still no luck.

Comment: In that case, this must be caused by a device driver. A far chance is to do a [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I did the in-place upgrade according to the instructions you linked to, that didn't fix it. I also reinstalled my GPU drivers, just for good measure, but that didn't help either. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Up till now, Autoruns found the problem in all such cases that I helped on this site. I find it astounding that this doesn't happen in Safe Mode but still happens when everything is disabled via Autoruns. I have no more ideas, sorry.

Comment: That's a bummer, but thank you for your patience anyway! The only idea I have left is to somehow try and basically debug `taskhostw`, investigate how the operations found by procmon and detailed in my question are called, but I don't have any idea how I would go about doing that. If that's not against superuser rules, may I ask you to share this question in chat (can't do it myself, not enough reputation) to try and find someone who might know how to do that?

Comment: Chat is not the right tool. Your post has stayed active and so on top of the stack for a couple of days now. People have seen it, and would have pitched in if they had different ideas. My only other idea is to re-install Windows from scratch, but that's rather heavy.

Comment: @harrymc Gotcha. I'll wait some more, maybe someone still has an idea. I really hope I won't have to reinstall Windows, because I did that just a few days ago.

Comment: If you reinstall, install products one-by-one while testing for the problem. You might find it this way.

Comment: Awesome investigation @Rummskartoffel. Any luck resolving the issue? My Windows 10 has been beeping for months now seemingly randomly. I didn't notice any patterns like yours. I heard it while Chrome or Android Studio was open, but probably other times too. These two I use a lot daily.

Comment: @TWiStErRob: I'm afraid I can't help you here. I just stopped using the keyboard layout that caused the issue and that was it, but since you don't know what causes it, that won't work for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with same issue and others like

- Failed to download any files in Firefox
- "Unable to extract 64-bit image. Run Process Explorer from a writable directory." when running Process Explorer, that just worked yesterday
- ... many other problems could arise.

The real reason was that I set a Junction (hard link) for Temp folder when I played with [ImDisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/). After unmounting the disk I got a broken link.

So deleting the "C:\ProgramData\Temp" (broken junction) fixes all the issues.
You don't even need to create it manually since first attempt to write to temp folder will create it.

It seems that the sound notification from taskhostw.exe was caused by unsuccessful attempt to use `%TEMP%` by different programs.